# nested list using nested foreach in php pdo

Tags: php, html, list, pdo, unordered

```html
<ul>
      <li>Main Menu 1
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Menu 1.1
          </li>
          <li>Sub Menu 1.2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Main Menu 2
        <ul>
          <li>Sub Menu 2.1
          </li>
          <li>Sub Menu 2.2
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Above is a representation of an unorderlist I am trying to make. I am able to make this kind of list using foreach, one function for getting the main menu and one function for getting the sub menu. I would like to solicit for suggestion on how to make a condition of some sort to determine which sub menu is for which menu because as of now all the sub menu are showing for all the menu at the same time. There should be a specific menu for a specific sub menu here is the code I work on

Server side

```js
function RetrieveAllMenu() {
  global $dbh;
  $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM userlist_tbl WHERE username = ?");
  $stmt - > bindValue(1, $_SESSION['login_user']);
  $stmt - > execute();
  $selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $mem_id = $selected_row['user_id'];
  if ($stmt - > execute()) {
    if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
      $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM rolemapping_tbl WHERE user_id = ?");
      $stmt - > bindValue(1, $mem_id);
      $stmt - > execute();
      $selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      $rolelist_id = $selected_row['rolelist_id'];
      if ($stmt - > execute()) {
        $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM roledetails_tbl WHERE rolelist_id = ?");
        $stmt - > bindValue(1, $rolelist_id);
        $stmt - > execute();
        $selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if ($stmt - > execute()) {
          if ($stmt - > rowCount() > 0) {
            $menu_id = array();
            while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              $menu_id[] = array('menuid' => $selected_row['menulist_id'], );
            }
            $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM menulist_tbl WHERE menulist_id = :menuid");
            $menu_name = array();
            foreach($menu_id as $row) {
              $stmt - > execute(array(':menuid' => $row['menuid']));
              //while ($selected_row =$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)){
              while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $menu_name[] = array('menuname' => $selected_row['menu_name'], 'menuurl' => $selected_row['menu_url'], 'menuflag' => $selected_row['menu_flag'], 'menuid' => $selected_row['menulist_id']);
              }
            }
            return $menu_name;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

function RetrieveAllSubMenu() {
  global $dbh;
  $menu_name = RetrieveAllMenu();
  $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM submenulist_tbl WHERE parent_id = :menuid");
  $submenu_name = array();
  foreach($menu_name as $row) {
      //$stmt->execute(array(':menuid' => $row['menuid']));
      $stmt - > bindValue(':menuid', $row['menuid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt - > execute();
      while ($selected_row = $stmt - > fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $submenu_name[] = array('submenuname' => $selected_row['submenulist_name'], 'submenuurl' => $selected_row['submenulist_url'], 'submenuflag' => $selected_row['submenulist_flag']);
      }
    }
    //print_r($submenu_name);
  return $submenu_name;
  //return in_array($menuid, $submenu_name);
}
```

This is html side

```js
<?php
echo'<ul>';   
foreach (RetrieveAllMenu() as $value){
//echo'<input  type="submit" value="'.$value['menuname'].'" name="'.$value['menuname'].'"/>';
echo'<li>';
echo '<a href="'.$value['menuurl'].'" id=""'.$value['menuname'].'"">'.$value['menuname'].'</a>';
echo'<ul>';
foreach (RetrieveAllSubMenu() as $value){
//if( $value['parentid'] === $value['menuid'] ){    
echo'<li><a href="'.$value['submenuurl'].'" id=""'.$value['submenuname'].'"">'.$value['submenuname'].'</a></li>';
//}
}
echo'</ul>';  
echo'</li>';         
}   
echo'</ul>';    
?>
```

This is how my code looks it should look like the one above.

```html
<ul>
          <li>Main Menu 1
            <ul>
              <li>Sub Menu 1.1
              </li>
              <li>Sub Menu 1.2
              </li>
               <li>Sub Menu 2.1
              </li>
              <li>Sub Menu 2.2
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>Main Menu 2
            <ul>
              <li>Sub Menu 1.1
              </li>
              <li>Sub Menu 1.2
              </li>
              <li>Sub Menu 2.1
              </li>
              <li>Sub Menu 2.2
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: sir @Arif_suhail_123 the stmt is ok my problem is with showing the submenu what happens is all submenu is showing for all menu. What i want is specific sub menu for specific menu

Comment: `RetrieveAllSubMenu` needs to take a parameter saying which menu it should get the submenus of.

Comment: It would be better if you did it all in one loop, using a join between the menu and submenu tables.

Comment: sir @Barmar can you give sample on how to make it sir i am not proficient enough in doing complicated database relations.or any link that point to your idea will really help.

Comment: I can't fit something like that in a comment. I guess you need to read a good SQL tutorial on joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your `RetrieveAllSubMenu()` function so that it returns only the submenus of a given menu by it's id and not for all menus

```
function RetrieveAllSubMenu($menu_id) {
  // your code
  $stmt = $dbh - > prepare("SELECT * FROM submenulist_tbl WHERE parent_id = :menuid");
      $stmt - > bindValue(':menuid', $menu_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 // more code
}
```

Giving you just the logic behind it but this will return the submenus for only one menu based on passed `$menu_id`.

So when trying to get the submenus your `foreach` should look something similar to this:

```
foreach (RetrieveAllSubMenu($value['menuid']) as $value){
```

I would also suggest you name your returned results for `$value` a bit better like:

```
foreach (RetrieveAllSubMenu($value['menuid']) as $submenu){
```

since you are also using `$value` for the menus and submenus this could lead to problems if you are not fully understanding when $value is overriden by the inner `foreach` statement

**EDIT**

Your foreach statements should look similar to:

```
foreach (RetrieveAllMenu() as $menu){
    echo'<li>';
    echo '<a href="'.$menu['menuurl'].'" id=""'.$menu['menuname'].'"">'.$menu['menuname'].'</a>';
    echo'<ul>';
    foreach (RetrieveAllSubMenu($menu['menuid']) as $submenu){
        echo'<li><a href="'.$submenu['submenuurl'].'" id=""'.$submenu['submenuname'].'"">'.$submenu['submenuname'].'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be `$menu_id = $value['menuid'];` in your example before retrieving the `RetrieveAllSubMenu` call

Comment: `retrieving the RetrieveAllSubMenu call` this part i dont understand is this in server side or html side?sorry about that i dont get it really please bear with me

Comment: i thought i was wrong my code is like that but still all menu is showing maybe i have it wrong in server side :) thank you for idea sir will up it very soon and tick it if its really what i want :)

Comment: one more thing can u ask about this `function RetrieveAllSubMenu($menu_id) {` why put `$menu_id` in and when i did this nothing new happened just out of curiosity.

Comment: If you copy/pasted it wouldn't work because i just saw that there was a typo in `$stmt - > bindValue(':menuid', $menu_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);` and `$menu_id` was `$menuid`. You pass that parameter so it only selects submenus with a parent id that is the same as the menu needed only

Comment: what i did is have an if condition then compare the menu_id to parent id and it worked..hopefully it wont bug